# Display the most popular post using laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel

I am newbie in Laravel Framework. I work in my project where i need to display the most popular post link in the website.
SO I used simple logic to stored each load of page and store the count the database table and sort it by values of the count.

My database Structure is:-

```
view_count|slug|created_at|updated_at
```

I want to store the value in view_count in each click of link(slug) and sort as per maximum number of view_count.
I am thankful if anyone help to solve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your model is called Post

```
Post::get()->sortByDesc('view_count');
```

Answer (score 0):

you dont mention what your model name and what have you tried.

I write a sample code hope it will help you

```
//let model name is post. and we select most popular 5 post
$latestPost = Post::OrderBy('view_count', 'DESC')->take(5);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($latestPost->toArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this `laravel` package

https://github.com/jordanmiguel/laravel-popular

i believe it solves your issue a bit faster